# Отправка уведомления из закрытого приложения

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Я хочу отправить уведомление из закрытого приложения, но оно не приходит. Что я делаю не так?

MainActivity

```java
public void DelayNotification(Notification notification, long futureInMillis, int id){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    //notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

Receiver

```java
package galimski.igor.com.do_ing;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="galimski.igor.com.do_ing">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddTaskActivity"></activity>

        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: При выгрузке приложения из памяти уведомления не приходят

Comment: Еще версию Андроида стоит указать. В вопросе.